# Repeated coin flips probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Assume in an experiment, one flips a coin $L$ times. This experiment is repeated N times. We represent these in a table with $N$ rows and $L$ columns with order.
So a column is defined at the position of the $k$'th flip ($1 \le \forall k \le L$) among all experiments.
If the head probability is $P_h$, then what is the probability of the following events:

1- "No two experiments share a heads in a column"

2- " In at least one column, all experiences are heads."

Also I would like to know what kind of random process can model this.

Hint: I guess this can be addressed as a special case of the birthday problem. Each experiment can be seen as a person while the "head" event is a kind of "birthday". So we have $N$ individuals to share / not share these events.

Comment: Questions that pose multiple problems, especially without an indication of effort to solve them by the poster, are apt to be closed as off-topic/lacking context.  See the [Help Center FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/help) for how to ask good questions.

Comment: The first of the two questions is so awkwardly stated that I cannot make sense of it. Perhaps an example of what is prohibited would help. But this question has been around for a while without response to @hardmath .

Comment: @BruceTrumbo: Given that the OP has not been "seen" recently, but in that absence the Question has been closed, edited, and reopened, yet without Answer, I'm inclined to post a CW Answer just for to sake of a resolution.

Answer (score 1):

The probabilities may be calculated, assuming all results are independent binomial outcomes.  Here $P_h$ is probability of a single coin toss resulting in *heads*.

Although framed as $N$ repetitions (the rows) of $L$ coin tosses, the first part lends itself more easily to considering $L$ repetitions (the columns) of $N$ coin tosses.  We are asked the chances that no column will contain more than one *head* entry, equiv. that we $L$ times get such an outcome, i.e. $Pr(\text{at most one head in }N\text{ tosses})^L$.  The probability of getting at most one *head* in $N$ attempts is $(1-P_h)^N + N P_h (1-P_h)^{N-1}$ by the usual binomial expansion.  So raise this to the power $L$ to answer the first part.

The second part also lends itself to considering the columns as independent trials.  The chance of getting all *heads* in a fixed column is $P_h^N$, so the probability that at least one column has all *heads* is the complement of having no columns with all *heads*:

$$ Pr(\text{at least one column all heads}) = 1 - (1-P_h^N)^L $$

Set to Community Wiki, so anyone who spots a mistake or lacuna should feel free to fix it.